# bottom vertical align an h3 text with 100% height

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

To be clear, I am not interested in vertical aligning the `h3` to the bottom of a div, or another block element. I know that already.

I have an `h3` with 100% height. I want to vertically align the text in the `h3` to the bottom.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lcvy/).

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
}
h3 {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

<div>
    <h3>Kitchen Experiments</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might do the trick.

For the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <h3>Kitchen Experiments</h3>
</div>
```

apply the following CSS:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid #666;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
}

h3 {
    height: inherit;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-color: pink; /* optional to show extent of element */
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
}
h3:after { /* trick to add bottom padding */
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 10px; 
}
```

Apply `display: table-cell` to `h3` and inherit the height (instead of 100%).

The parent `div` is still a block element, so it will probably behave responsively (but you need to try this yourself).

If you need to control the bottom padding between the text and the parent block,
you can include the rule with the pseudo-element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/RJ6YM/

Answer (score 4):

Write:

```
div {
    display:table;
}

h3 {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lcvy/1/)

Comment: +1 Great tip, but I can't do `display: table;` - It messes up my responsive layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by absolute positioning of your `H3` element inside the div. Here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Lcvy/2/

Comment: That does not fit my needs; it removes my `height: 100%` height requirement.

Comment: And why is that a requirement?

Comment: It does not matter, but there's a good reason for it. It's too long for a comment, but my question specifically states that requirement.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton very well then, but how about encapsulating the text inside your <h3> in a span that you can position relative to the h3. There's no clean solution for your problem.

Comment: What the hell, let me explain: The surrounding div needs to be clickable. It redirects to a location via JS. But the div has an ajax button, which, when clicked, should carry out a different request. Unfortunately the click event propagates from the button to the div, and cancels the ajax request as it carries out the redirect. Calling `e.stopPropagation()` breaks the ajax. Having 100% height allows me to make the `h3` clickable without sacrificing the button's ajax.

Answer (score 1):

For those who can use flexbox, here's a flex alternative:

```
div {        
  display: flex;
  ...
}

h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/62a7djxh/1/